# My php code for importing file and populating it in database using yii2 not working

Tags: php, database, yii2

Here is my code and imgetting following error when i import the file from my wsp folder web/name of the file
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
move_uploaded_file(uploads/DokoloDistrict.csv): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

1. in /home/esther/yii2_trainning/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/UploadedFile.phpat line 197
   I tried uploading different files but none worked .Is there an issue with my code or is it only the file path that is the issue

```php
public function actionImportcsv()
{
    $model = new Members();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $csvFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'csvFile');

        if ($csvFile) {
            $filePath = 'uploads/' . $csvFile->baseName . '.' . $csvFile->extension;
            $csvFile->saveAs($filePath);

            // insert CSV data into the database
            $this->importCsvData($filePath);

            // unlink the file after processing
            unlink($filePath);

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'CSV data imported successfully.');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Error uploading CSV file.');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('import', ['model' => $model]);
}

private function importCsvData($filePath)
{
    $handle = fopen($filePath, 'r');

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        $model = new Members();
        $model->phone = $data[0]; 
        $model->name = $data[1];
        

        $model->save();
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: It will be the path.  Try creating the folder first FileHelper::createDirectory($path, $mode = 0775, $recursive = true);  Then search on the server for the folder and file.